# Como resolver problema de codificação GIT DIFF

Tags: git, utf-8, diff

Para alguns arquivos, o git diff me apresenta � ao invés de caracteres com acentos. Eu não sei realmente se o problema é o git diff.
O GUI que estou usando é o Git Kraken. Segue abaixo um print do erro.

[image: Erro no git diff]

Comment: Você setou a codificação no seu arquivo? Pois o git apenas lê o arquivo

Comment: como vejo isso?@Diego

Comment: Pelo Windows você consegue mudar pelo próprio Notepad++ e pelo Linux você pode utilizar o comando 'iconv': https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Consertando-codificacao-de-arquivos-UTF-8-x-ISO-8859-1